# How to add custom fields in <message> elements of XMPP stanza/packet?

Tags: android, xmpp

I want to send

```
<message id="qm5Dx-8"
 to="abc"
 type="chat" 
 from="abc"
 msgType="2"
 msgTimeStamp="1413971599039"
 fileSize="18 MB" 
 fileHeight="300"
 fileWidth="300"
 thumbnail="abc"
 mediaURL=""
 serverMediaURL="xyz"
 isFromMe="1"
 status="1"><body>Image</body><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></message>
```

The way i am constructing the custom message is :

```
public class MyCustomMessage  extends Message{

    public MyCustomMessage(){
        super();
    }

    public MyCustomMessage(String to, Type type){
        super(to, type);
    }
    private String msgType ;
    private String msgTimeStamp ;
    private String isFromMe ;
    private String status ;
    private String mediaURL ;
    private String serverMediaURL ;
    private String fileSize ;
    private String fileHeight ;
    private String fileWidth ;
    private String thumbnail ;

    @Override
    public String toXML() {
        String XMLMessage = super.toXML();
        String XMLMessage1 = XMLMessage.substring(0, XMLMessage.indexOf(">"));
        String XMLMessage2 = XMLMessage.substring(XMLMessage.indexOf(">"));

        if (this.msgType != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " msgType=\"" + this.msgType + "\"";
        }
        if (this.msgTimeStamp != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " msgTimeStamp=\"" + this.msgTimeStamp + "\"";
        }
        if (this.fileSize != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " fileSize=\"" + this.fileSize + "\"";
        }
        if (this.fileHeight != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " fileHeight=\"" + this.fileHeight + "\"";
        }
        if (this.fileWidth != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " fileWidth=\"" + this.fileWidth + "\"";
        }
        if (this.thumbnail != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " thumbnail=\"" + this.thumbnail + "\"";
        }
        if (this.mediaURL != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " mediaURL=\"" + this.mediaURL + "\"";
        }
        if (this.serverMediaURL != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " serverMediaURL=\"" + this.serverMediaURL + "\"";
        }
        if (this.isFromMe != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " isFromMe=\"" + this.isFromMe + "\"";
        }
        if (this.status != null) {
            XMLMessage1 += " status=\"" + this.status + "\"";
        }

        return XMLMessage1 + XMLMessage2;
    }

// Setters Getters of all these fields..

}
```

Then after adding required fields in SmackableImplement class, i m calling **mXMPPConnection.sendPacket(customMessage);**

but m not receiving any packet. my connections is being closed everytime after calling this method. I have gone through many tutorials but couldnt find any solution...tell me where m mistaken.

Answer (score 6):

1. Smack surely has a better way to work with XML than this approach with modifying the string representation. This will break badly when anything contains a `"` or any of the other characters that need to be escaped as an attribute.
2. You have to add custom payloads to messages as a separate XML element within the message, not as attributes on the message. Your XML should look like:

   ```
    <message id="qm5Dx-8" to="abc" type="chat" from="abc">
       <body>Image</body>
       <request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>
       <data xmlns='http://bstkaal/custom/data'
         msgType="2"
         msgTimeStamp="1413971599039"
         fileSize="18 MB" 
         fileHeight="300"
         fileWidth="300"
         thumbnail="abc"
         mediaURL=""
         serverMediaURL="xyz"
         isFromMe="1"
         status="1" />
   </message>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

[xnyhps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26509393/194894) answer is correct. I've just want to add a few things. He already said that, but I can't stress the fact enough, because I see it again and again:

**Never add custom values to specified stream element attributes (e.g. a new value for the type attribute of messages), and never add new attributes to top level elements (like you did with `msgType`, `msgTimeStamp` and so on).**

This has the potential to break things! Don't do it. See also ["XEP-0134: XMPP Design Guidelines § 2.1 XMPP is Sacred"](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0134.html#xmpp). That's why it's not possible in Smack. Instead, use a custom extension element, like xnyhps showed in his example (the `data` element). See also ["RFC 6120 § 8.4 Extended Content"](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-extended) Those are called [PacketExtension](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/PacketExtension.html)'s in Smack.

Comment: as u said, i have tried PacketExtension, but not getting my results. can u plz look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577323/not-getting-xmpp-message-xml-as-it-was-sent