# How to read custom attributes of xmpp message tag in android?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

The xml that i need to receive is :

```
<message id="qm5Dx8" to="adsfxcv" type="chat"from="adsf"
 msgType="2"
 thumbnail="randomThumbnail"
 serverMediaURL="random"
 isFromMe="1"
 status="1"><body>Image</body><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></message>
```

Message is being sent by **MyCustomMessage extends Message** class.

In my message listener, Where i need to get the packet is :

```
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            String recivedPacket = packet.toXML();
            try {
                if (packet instanceof MyCustomMessage) {
                    MyCustomMessage msg = (MyCustomMessage) packet;
                    ....
```

But I am receiving only id,to,type and from in message tag. And the instance of packet is also of Message and it says , cannot cast packet to message. plz guide me how can i receive my desired packet.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Also you should never extend the `Message` or `Presence` class.

**Never add custom values to specified stream element attributes (e.g. a new value for the type attribute of messages), and never add new attributes to top level elements (like you did with `msgType`, `msgTimeStamp` and so on).**

This has the potential to break things! Don't do it. See also ["XEP-0134: XMPP Design Guidelines § 2.1 XMPP is Sacred"](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0134.html#xmpp). That's why it's not possible in Smack. Instead, use a custom extension element, like xnyhps showed in his example (the `data` element). See also ["RFC 6120 § 8.4 Extended Content"](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-extended) Those are called [PacketExtension](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/PacketExtension.html)'s in Smack.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26509393/194894) and question.