# How to read custom attributes added in message tag of xmpp in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmpp, smack

The `XMPP` message being sent has some custom attribtes added in message tag like :

```
<message to = " asdf" from = "asdf" type = "chat" id="adsf" direction = "asdf" speed = "asdf">
<body>Speed</body>
</message>
```

Message that is being sent is all fine. But on receiving end , I dnt know how to read these extra attributes i.e. **`direction and speed`** added in message tag. I tried to make custom **`PacketListener`** but for that i need to change the whole smack library bcz every class is connected to other class.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516386

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

**Never add custom values to specified stream element attributes (e.g. a new value for the type attribute of messages), and never add new attributes to top level elements (like you did with `msgType`, `msgTimeStamp` and so on).**

This has the potential to break things! Don't do it. See also ["XEP-0134: XMPP Design Guidelines § 2.1 XMPP is Sacred"](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0134.html#xmpp). That's why it's not possible in Smack. Instead, use a custom extension element, like xnyhps showed in his example (the `data` element). See also ["RFC 6120 § 8.4 Extended Content"](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-extended) Those are called [PacketExtension](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/PacketExtension.html)'s in Smack.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26509393/194894) and question.