# How to send custom presence (XMPP)?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I use Smack lib. I need to send this(Android):

```
<presence type='initialize' location_id='570' user_id='8942'/>.
```

On Xcode:

```
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    [presence addAttributeWithName:@"location_id" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)Settings.LocationID]];
    [presence addAttributeWithName:@"user_id" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)Settings.UserID]];
    [presence addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"initialize"];
    [_xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

Comment: Can we have a bit more info on your issue ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        presence.setProperty("location_id","123");
        connection.sendPacket(presence);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The value 'initialize' is not defined for the 'type' attribute of presences. Nor are 'location_id' or 'user_id'. If you want to add custom information to stanzas, use extension elements:

```
<presence ...>
  <myExtension xmlns='myns'>
    <initialize location_id='570' user_id='8942'/>
  </myExtension>
</presence>
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544842/194894