# Using XMPP for chat and notification service

Tags: javascript, html, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I want to set up an XMPP chat and notification service.
What I figured out so far is the following: I set up ejabberd and used strophe.js to connect to the BOSH, set the presence, send and receive messages.
Though this post is a theoretical question, I hope I still get help.

Next to sending chat messages (which is fairly easy) I want to send notification updates with data that i store in an array. I usually use JSON to do the job, yet XMPP is XML orientated and javascript on the client side is not goin to be happy about getting an xml like array. What is the best way to send this data?

Is there any chance to use different types of messages to figure out which kind of notification it is?

```
<message to='romeo@montague.net' id='message22' **type="profile_update"**>
  <body>data</body>
  <x xmlns='jabber:x:event'>
    <offline/>
  </x>
</message>
```

I hope it can be understood what I am talkin about exactly.
So thanks in advance for your answers.

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Never use custom attributes or values for the `message` element, use an extension element instead. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/26510821/194894

Comment: OK, Thank you for the input. And i guess i can interpret the attributes of data pasing it with jQuery and receiving the values for attributes

Comment: Do u think that would be a convenient way?