# How can I add custom attribute (nick) in my XMPP message tag, in Smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I want to add **custom attribute (nick)** in my XMPP chat message, like the following example

```
<message from='*' to='*' id='123' nick='KASHIF' type='chat'><body>hello</body></message>
```

I know, it is **not recommended** by XMPP but it is my requirement as this **attribute(nick)** is already implemented in the iOS version of the app i am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to edit 2 classes of Smack 4.1

- **Stanza** class in (**org.jivesoftware.smack.packet**)
- **PacketParserUtils** class in (**org.jivesoftware.smack.util**)

***1. Stanza class***

Define your custom attribute (**nick**)

```
 private String nick = null;
```

Define Getter and Setters

```
public String getNick() {
    return this.nick;
}

public void setNick(String paramString) {
   this.nick = paramString;
}
```

Edit Stanza *Constructor*

```
protected Stanza(Stanza p) {

   //add this line
   nick = p.getNick();

}
```

Edit *addCommonAttributes* method

```
protected void addCommonAttributes(XmlStringBuilder xml) {

    //add this line
    if(getNick()!= null)
         xml.optAttribute("nick", getNick());
}
```

***2. PacketParserUtils class***

Edit *parseMessage* method

```
 public static Message parseMessage(XmlPullParser parser)
                throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, SmackException {

   //add this line
   message.setNick(parser.getAttributeValue("", "nick"));

}
```

**Now you can simply set nick and send message as follows**

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setType(Message.Type.chat);
message.setStanzaId("123");
message.setTo(number);

message.setNick("SHAYAN");    

try {
 connection.sendStanza(message);
} catch (NotConnectedException e) {
}
```

Comment: Hi shanrais!, I cloned Smack from github and I edited two classes. But, you didn't say how to deploy smack and create jars again to Android with right ?

Comment: Instead of creating Jars, What I have done is included the source code of that jar which I have edited in my project.

Comment: can you say which folders need copy? Have many folders in project https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack on github, I don't know which folders need copy to my project. Following jars declared in my app gradle:                                                                                                        compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.1'

Comment: Do not copy smack-core-4.1.0.jar in your lib folder.
Just copy the code of smack-core-4.1.0-sources in your project.

Comment: can you example project? I added just source code smack-core-4.1.0-sources but appear another error: not found import org.jxmpp.jid.DomainBareJid;
import org.jxmpp.jid.parts.Resourcepart;

Comment: try copying both code(smack-core-4.1.0-sources) + library(smack-core-4.1.0.jar) in your lib folder

Comment: Hey @shanrais I need to do the same thing in my app. Can you please tell me exact steps of doing it? As there are so many projects so I am really confused.

Comment: Is there any way to add custom attributes without modifying smack library ?

Comment: you can use this approach : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26509393/4754141 or use extension as mentioned by the xnyhps below http://stackoverflow.com/a/30161833/4754141

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that, it's not recommended for a reason. It's very likely some servers will strip the attribute or even completely refuse to handle the packet. Instead, the recommended way is to add a custom element.

In fact, such an extension already exists, [XEP-0172](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html):

```
<message from='*' to='*' id='123' type='chat'>
    <nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>KASHIF</nick>
    <body>hello</body>
</message>
```

This might already work with other clients or libraries, so it's a much better solution.

Comment: in my case, this will crash the iOS version of the app