# attach files in converse js chat functionality using openfire

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, converse.js

I want to setup chat functionality in my web app using Openfire  and converse.js
I am planning to implement an archiving feature to the chat. I have already installed the Monitoring Service plugin of Openfire and can now generate conversation history report in the admin console. 
Now I am planning to implement file attachment in chat. so is it possible using converse.js and Openfire??

Answer (score 0):

Yes , It is possible. You can read this for more details http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html

Answer (score 0):

You can save links to your attachments by customizing your stanza accordingly to store the url to the attachment. But be careful not to modify the message stanza directly check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507753/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-message-elements-of-xmpp-stanza-packet). Instead you can add your custom stanza as payload xml to the message stanza.